# EntityFramework multiplicity error on removal of an item from a collection

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm

I have a parent object with this schema:

```
public class User : EntityBase
{
    private List<UserCompany> _UserCompanies = new List<UserCompany>();

    // The list of companies the user can act upon, with a flag indicating their Primary company
    public virtual List<UserCompany> UserCompanies
    {
        get { return _UserCompanies; } 
        set { _UserCompanies = value; }
    }
}
```

and a child object that looks like this:

```
public class UserCompany : EntityBase
{
    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

Both inherit from the EntityBase class:

```
  public abstract class EntityBase
  {
    protected int _id;

    /// <summary>Database record ID.</summary>
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id
    {
      get { return _id; }
      set { _id = value; }
    }
  }
```

The objects have no explicit model configuration, except this generic one:

```
public EntityBaseConfiguration()
{
  HasKey(m => m.Id);
  Property(m => m.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that removing a UserCompany from the User.UserCompanies collection results in this error:

***A relationship from the 'UserCompany_User' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'UserCompany_User_Source' must also in the 'Deleted' state.***

My interpretation of this error is that it wants the User object to be marked Deleted as well, which is not my intention.  Can anyone advise how to successfully delete the UserCompany object in this case (without deleting User or Company)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's going on. A `UserCompany` can't exist without a related user (because `UserCompany.User` is marked as required. When you remove a UserCompany from a user's UserCompanies collection Entity Framework will try to do only that: remove the association, not the UserCompany. EF rather errs on the side of caution and will not assume you *also* want delete the object. It will try to nullify the foreign key in stead - but it can't.

So you have to delete the UserCompany object explcitly:

```
context.UserCompanies.Remove(userCompany);
```

or

```
context.Entry(userCompany).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```